# What is a test called that involves indicating whether a line has the same slope as a previous image?

Tags: terminology, memory, test

I would like to know the name of the following test:

Participants were asked to memorize the slope of a line of a target image. 
Then different images (lines with varying slopes) were presented sequentially. Participants were asked to press one of two buttons to indicate whether the displayed image was the same or different to the target image.

- Is it a recognition memory test?
- Does this test have a specific name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The task sounds like a [match-to-sample task](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Match-to-sample_task) which is indeed used in working memory studies. In this test participants are presented with a sample stimulus and have to judge whether or not following stimuli resemble this particular stimulus. Depending on the time span between the presentation of the sample stimulus and the following stimuli this task is sometimes also called a delayed match-to-sample task.

Comment: As I understand in match-to-sample task probe item presented simultaneously. In my test they presented sequentially.

Comment: I believe that match-to-sample, also called XAB, does not necessarily refer to tasks in which the probe items are presented simultaneously. See e.g. [link](http://people.ucsc.edu/~gmcguir1/experiment_designs.pdf), which uses these terms in the context of auditory stimuli which would necessarily be presented sequentially. I don't think it would be correct to refer to it as a recognition memory task - I've more often seen it used as a measure of perceptual discrimination.